# Stop Developer to user same Session name in multi-developer environment

Tags: asp.net

I am handling a team of 10-15 developer of ASP.NET (4.0), how could i stop them to use same Session name in their code?
or 
in other words, how could a developer come to know that Session name is already exist so that he should use some other name.
In my case every developer is using Session["ID"], i want, if Session["ID"] is already used then developer might get some sort of information so that he should not use same  session name.

May be this could be easy or off the track.. but i am facing this problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are talking about ensuring that developers don't all use the same keys for Session values.

Establishing naming conventions may be the simplest way to address the concern.

I also find it helpful to wrap Session-related values in helper class(es) to avoid this problem and also to make the consumption of such data cleaner (and more abstracted).

### Example

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static UserId
    {
       get{ return (int)Session["UserId"]; }
       set{ Session["UserId"] = value; }
    }
}
```

As long as you are using proper source control, any conflicts will become quickly apparent.

If you want to make the key names *really* obvious, then you could manage them as separate fields in the class all grouped together in the same place.

```
public static class MyClass
{
    private static readonly string _userIdKey = "UserId";
    private static readonly string _anotherKey = "AnotherKey";

    public static UserId
    {
       get{ return (int)Session[_userIdKey ]; }
       set{ Session[_userIdKey ] = value; }
    }
}
```

Lastly, you could run unit tests against these helper class(es) to ensure that keys were not being overwritten although this is probably overkill.

Comment: Thanks TIM, i use second option :)